# Granular Firebase security for update() call

Tags: firebase

[Firebase.update()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/update.html) is hugely useful to atomically update multiple nodes. However, it appears limited as the Security rules is still defined by the root node in the `update()` operation.

For example, let's say my data is structured as:

```
users : {
    uid : {account: accountId, ...},
    ...
},
accounts : {
    accountId : {uid: uid, ....},
    ...
},
customers : {
    customerId : {uid: uid, accountId: accountId...},
    ...
}
```

My Firebase security is organized as:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "users" : {
            "$uid" : {
                ".read": "data.child('account').val() === root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('account').val()",
                ".write": "data.child('account').val() === root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('account').val()" 
              }
        },
        "accounts" : {
              "$accountId” : {
                    ".read": "data.child('users').child(auth.uid).exists() || newData.child('users').child(auth.uid).exists()",
                    ".write": "data.child('users').child(auth.uid).exists() || newData.child('users').child(auth.uid).exists()"
              }
        },
        “customers” : {
              "$customerId” : {
                  ".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('account').val() == root.child('customers').child($customerId).child('account').val()",
                  ".write": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('account').val() == root.child('customers').child($customerId).child('account').val()" 
                }
        }
   }
```

To make an atomic update for a given businessId across these nodes, I can make an `update()` call as such:

```
firebaseRef.update({
    accounts : {
        accountId : { foo: bar },
    },
    customers : {
        customerId : { foo: bar },
    }
}
```

Since `update()` should only modify the specified locations, the node-by-node security rules could apply (e.g. using `uid`). However, it seems that the root security (e.g. `/`) prevails and I get a warning as such:

```
FIREBASE WARNING: update at / failed: permission_denied
```

So now I'm instead using a promise chain to update the different nodes in sequence using `set()` which means I lose the atomic operation.

Is there a better way to make atomic operations across multiple nodes without having to open up security for the root?

Comment: Can you please post your rules (as text) for the above firebase structure?

Comment: Hi Jay! Sorry for the late response. My application is a bit too complex to post the full security rules and couldn't think of a simple way to replicate the problem. But in general, should an update() call work on the root node if all the updated sub-nodes pass security? If so, it's probably an incorrect security setting on my behalf right now.

Comment: did you solved the issue?

Comment: No, I'm still doing this as a promise chain instead of the fan-out method because of the security issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your security rules `root` refers to the current/old data at the root. If you want to access the new data at the root, you have to navigate to it from `newData`:

```
".read": "newData.parent().parent().child('businessDta')...
```

Our Bolt language has a special shortcut, when you use `root` there it will actually generate the necessary `newData.parent().parent()...` calls for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this issue and I solved it by fixing the security rules for each path in the updates. Turns out the SDK works well with the `update()` and security rules.

For your case, you may want to double check the security rules for both `/accounts/accountId` and `/customers/customerId` are working well for your `update()` call. You can debug this by separate the update into the original `set()` call to test if the every single update path is working with the rules.

However, I think you may have a typo in the rules of "/accounts/$accountId". You may need to do `root.child("users")` instead of `data.child("users")`